# Javascript+Select динамика

Tags: javascript, html

Понимающие в JavaScript - откликнитесь. Вообщем ситуашка следующяя.
Есть форма

```
<form name="catalog" action="" method="POST">
<div align="center" style="border: solid 1px #cccccc;">
<table style="margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="middle">
<td align="right">Выбор значения:</td><td nowrap>
<select class=select id="brands_id" name="category" onchange="catalog_rebuild(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"><option value="0">---
<option value="1">Какое-то значение первого селекта
</select>
<select id="models_id" name="car" class=select><option value="0">---</select>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function catalog_rebuild(a){
switch (a) {
case '0':
with (document.catalog.car) {
options.length = 0;
options[0] = new Option('---', '0');
selectedIndex = 0;
}; break;
case '1': with (document.catalog.car) {
    options.length= 0;
    options[0]= new Option('---','0');
    options[1]= new Option('Какое-то значение второго select','2');
    options[2]= new Option('Какое-то значение второго select','3');
    selectedIndex=0;
        }; break;
}
}
function catalog_init(){
catalog_rebuild(document.catalog.category.options[document.category.selectedIndex].value);
for (var i=0; i<document.catalog.car.options.length; i++) {
if (document.catalog.car.options[i].value== selected_car) {
document.catalog.car.options[i].selected= true;
}
}
}
var selected_category = 0;
var selected_car = 0;
catalog_init();
//--></script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Со скриптом заполнения - select-ов по выбраному value. Но форма робит только на 2 select тега. Сообственно мне нужно следующее: при выборе из 1 -го selecta значения второй select автоматически заполняется нужными нам значениями, а уже при выборе значения из второго select автоматически заполнялся значениями 3 select. И наконец, живой пример того, что я хочу: Допустим выбираю "Мороженое" - следующее меню мне дает список сиропа к мороженому - выбираю "сироп клубничный" - следующий список выводит "в стаканчике" или "в чащечке" - ну и дальше по списку.
Чтобы вопрос стал понятнее создайте фаил index.html и вставьте в него мой код. Увидите результат.

Comment: И в чём проблема? =) По аналогии сделать ж можно ^^ Будьте внимательнее - проверил копипастой - работает.

Comment: По аналогии?? Тобишь присвоить вторую функцию ко второму селектору и уже к этой функции привязать switch  с новой переменной??

Comment: Да, хоть это и бякокод, но работать будет) И делать лучше по тому способу, который предложили.

Answer (score 4):

Жесть, технологию ajax не хотите использовать? :)

Ну не хотите, так не хотите. Вот так должна выглядеть структура того, что вы хотите:

```
var s_arr1 = ['Мороженное', 'Диваны'];
var s_arr2 = {
    '0': ['В стаканчике', 'В чем-нибудь еще'], 
    '1':['Деревянный', 'Для садо-мазо']
};
var s_arr3 = {'0': // Берем первый элемент из s_arr1
    {'0': // Берем первый элемент из s_arr2
         ['Ну значит в стаканчике', 'Ну или не в стаканчике']
    }
}
```